# Display Invalid Characters Contained In File Extension or General String

Tags: vb.net

Display Invalid Characters Contained In File Extension or General String

I want to display the characters {}@ from ".R {t} F@" to the user as the invalid characters. I don't see my mistake as { } @ are not matched. The RegEx Pattern seems to be valid.

Tried using Expresso to find my problem but no luck.  Looked at various RegEx invalid character routines but my RegEx Pattern is similar to those.

Please tell me what my mistake is. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub TestBed()
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim MatchChars As String
    Dim Value As String = ".R {t} F@"
    Dim RxPattern As String = "^\.[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$"

    Msg = Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    MatchChars = Nothing

    For Each CharMatch As Match In Regex.Matches(Value, RxPattern)
        If MatchChars Is Nothing Then
            MatchChars = CharMatch.ToString
        Else
            If Not MatchChars.Contains(CharMatch.ToString) Then
                MatchChars = MatchChars & CharMatch.ToString
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If MatchChars Is Nothing Then
        Msg = Msg & Value
    Else
        Msg = Msg & MatchChars
    End If
    MsgBox(Msg)
End Sub
```

Comment: This code does not compile with [BC30469](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30469). Please post actual code.

Comment: Sorry GSerg.  Code  corrected, should now compile

Comment: We don't do signatures around here since your name is already listed under the question.

Comment: Your regex matches the entire string as a whole, not individual characters. Because the string does not conform to the pattern, `Regex.Matches` is empty and the `For Each` does not execute. If you need per-character matches, that would be `Dim RxPattern As String = "[^.a-zA-Z0-9\s]"`.

Comment: Sorry about the signature.  It is an old habit.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It is really appreciated.